# Understanding Input of BERT pre-training

Tags: bert-language-model, large-language-model

I have a question about BERT's pre-training -
The [original paper](https://aclanthology.org/N19-1423.pdf) mentions that MLM and NSP are done simultaneously. How does this work exactly?

Let's say we have a sample

[CLS] Sentence 1 [SEP] Sentence 2,

such that Sentence 1 and Sentence 2 are not consecutive.

Are any tokens in Sentence 1 or Sentence 2 masked in such a case? If so, how is the masked language modeling loss calculated? What are the ground truths?

Ground Truth for NSP = False
Ground Truth for MLM = ?

This is mostly an implementation based question.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-training is not a single step process. It has two steps.
Suppose one batch of data comes in the training process.

first, we will create a masked data **from** the original batch (we will not modify the original batch as it will be used again in the NSP task) and send this masked data to MLM task, then we'll calculate the **MLM loss** and apply backpropagation.

Now in the second step the original batch data comes to the NSP task, in which we will calculate the **NSP loss**. and apply backpropagation for this loss.

Note: I am not an expert. I don't know exactly how the original pretraining was done. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be super helpful if you could mention a source/tutorial that implements this. I had a followup -

Let's say the current sample has two non-consecutive sequences. It makes sense to calculate the NSP loss. However, if the MLM loss is calculated for this task, is there a danger that the model learns spurious correlations (because the two sentences are not continuous but we are still feeding it that information to predict the masked tokens)?

Comment: I was finetuning Bert for multitasking. And I give this answer inspired from that. You can see any code/blog on how multitasking work to get an idea about that.

Comment: That's fair. I will take a look at it.